# Python Pipeline Custom Transformer

Tags: python, pipeline, transformer-model

I am trying to code a custom transformer to be used in a pipeline to pre-process data.

Here is the code I'm using (sourced - not written by me).  It takes in a dataframe, scales the features, and returns a dataframe:

```
class DFStandardScaler(BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self):

        self.ss = None

    def fit(self,X,y=None):

        self.ss = StandardScaler().fit(X)
        return self

    def transform(self, X):

        Xss = self.ss.transform(X)
        Xscaled = pd.DataFrame(Xss, index=X.index, columns=X.columns)
        return Xscaled
```

I have data that has both categorical and continuous features.  Obviously the transformer will not transform the categorical feature ('sex').  When I fit this pipeline with the dataframe below it throws an error because it is trying to scale the categorical labels in 'sex':

```
     sex  length  diameter  height  whole_weight  shucked_weight  \
0      M   0.455     0.365   0.095        0.5140          0.2245   
1      M   0.350     0.265   0.090        0.2255          0.0995   
2      F   0.530     0.420   0.135        0.6770          0.2565   
3      M   0.440     0.365   0.125        0.5160          0.2155   
4      I   0.330     0.255   0.080        0.2050          0.0895   
5      I   0.425     0.300   0.095        0.3515          0.1410
```

How do I pass a list of categorical / continuous features into the transformer so it will scale the proper features?  Or is it better to somehow code the feature type check inside the transformer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need another step in the Pipeline with a similar class inheriting from `BaseEstimator` and `TransformerMixin`

```py
class ColumnSelector(BaseEstimator,TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, columns: list):
        self.cols = columns

    def fit(self,X,y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        return X.loc[:, self.cols]
```

Then in your main the pipeline looks like this:

```
selector = ColumnSelector(['length', 'diameter', 'height', 'whole_weight', 'shucked_weight'])
pipe = pipeline.make_pipeline(
    selector,
    DFStandardScaler()
)

pipe2 = pipeline.make_pipeline(#some steps for the sex column)

full_pipeline = pipeline.make_pipeline(
    pipeline.make_union(
        pipe,
        pipe2
    ),
    #some other step
)
```

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly I create a subset of the original data frame by passing in a list of the continuous features before entering the pipeline and then that dataframe is utilized in the pipeline where you have 'selector' and that is what gets processed in DFStandardScaler()?

I see you make a feature union with pipe2 for processing the categorical.  After exiting the featureunion at #some other step I would then need a process that concatonates the processed categoricals from pipe 2 and coninuous from pipe 1 into a single dataframe again? right?

Comment: Exactly! The only thing you do not need to do is the concat layer,  that's handled by the make Union and most sklearn models handle the output fine

Comment: One more thing.  I did as you suggested.  I'm just running pipe1 right now (continuous features).  When I run `pipeline.fit(X)` where `X` is the above data frame  I get the following result:  `Pipeline(memory=None,
     steps=[('column_selector', column_selector(columns=None)), ('scaler', DFStandardScaler())])` .  It doesn't seem to be recognizing the list of columns I'm passing into `column_selector`?

Comment: Figured it out.  I needed to do a `transform`.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Saw it now! Glad you figured it out, basically you want to run `fit_transform()` on the entire pipeline either in steps or end to end